# Validar fecha pero no requerida

Tags: laravel, validación

tengo el campo date_down que es para indicar la fecha de baja de un empleado. El cual no es obligatorio porque el empleado puede seguir activo en la nomina, pero quiero que si se completa el campo se valide que sea una fecha correcta.

Trate de aplicar una regla de validacion date_down = > date, pero eso me arroja que el campo es requerido si el imput esta vacio.

Nose si se entiende
El campo puede estar vacio, pero se se completa necesito que valide que sea una fecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes incluirlo en el array antes de validarlo

```
$validations = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
];

if($request->filled('date_down') {
    $validations['date_down'] = 'date';
}

$request->validate($validations);
```